# sed regex not being greedy?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, grep

In bash I have a string variable `tempvar`, which is created thus:

```
tempvar=`grep -n 'Mesh Tally' ${meshtalfile}`
```

`meshtalfile` is a (large) input file which contains some header lines and a number of blocks of data lines, each marked by a beginning line which is searched for in the grep above.

In the case at hand, the variable `tempvar` contains the following string:

```
5: Mesh Tally Number 4 977236: Mesh Tally Number 14 1954467: Mesh Tally Number 24 4354479: Mesh Tally Number 34
```

I now wish to extract the line number relating to a particularly mesh tally number - so I define a variable meshnum1 as equal to `24`, and run the following sed command:

```
echo ${tempvar} | sed -r "s/^.*([0-9][0-9]*):\sMesh\sTally\sNumber\s${meshnum1}.*$/\1/"
```

This is where things go wrong. I expect the output `1954467`, but instead I get `7`. Trying with number `34` instead returns `9` instead of `4354479`. It seems that sed is returning only the last digit of the number - which surely violates the principle of greedy matching? And oddly, when I move the open parenthesis `(` left a couple of characters to include `.*`, it returns the whole line up to and including the single character it was previously returning. Surely it cannot be greedy in one situation and antigreedy in another? Hopefully I have just done something stupid with the syntax...

Comment: There's a * missing in that sed. Don't know how that happened - I cut'n'pasted the whole line. Very strange. Should read: echo ${tempvar} | sed -r "s/^.*([0-9][0-9]*):\sMesh\sTally\sNumber\s${meshnum1}.*$/\1/"

Comment: You might want to edit your answer to prefix the "code" or "command" lines by four spaces, this changes the formatting. Because posts use mark-up, "normal" text (ie. not code for example) treats special characters for special functions, for example the * can be used to make text italic or used twice to make it bold. I think there is a help in the post edit box =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `.*` is being greedy too, which means that it will get all numbers too. Since you force it to get at least one digit in the `[0-9][0-9]*` part, the `.*` before it will be greedy enough to leave only one digit for the expression after it.

A solution could be:

```
echo ${tempvar} | sed -r "s/^.*\s([0-9][0-9]*):\sMesh\sTally\sNumber\s${meshnum1}.*$/\1/"
```

Where now the `\s` between the `.*` and the `[0-9][0-9]*` explictly forces there to be a space before the digits you want to match.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Thanks - with the addition of some dummy text and whitespace to the start of tempvar, this does the job. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Are the values in $tempvar supposed to be multiple or a single line? Because if it is a single line, ".*$" should match to the end of line, meaning all the other values too, right?

Comment: I know, sorry, but my rep is not high enough let me comment the question. Can you add this as a comment? I will remove my answer afterwards (if possible)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for `sed`, here's one way using `GNU grep`:

```
echo "$tempvar" | grep -oP "[0-9]+(?=:\sMesh\sTally\sNumber\s${meshnum1}\b)"
```

Comment: Thanks also. Thought there must be a way to do it with grep, but didn't have the knowledge...